# kml path in wordpress gets 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404, kml

I'm trying to use leaflet js on a wordpress website to display a map and a area with a kml file.

the script is displaying the map fine but not the kml layer. It failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) with the kml path.

But it's working fine on my local one so I don't get it...

Here the working path on my local wordpress:

```
var track = new L.KML("/wp-content/themes/mytheme/_include/97.kml", {async: true});
```

Any tip would be appreciated,

Thank You!

Comment: Have you tried using the absolute URL path; e.g. http://... or relative path; ./wp-conent/... ?

Comment: yeah I tried everything but I still get this error: GET 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Is the KML file actually there on the server (if you enter that URL in the browser, Google Earth or Booble Maps)?  Is your [server configured to  serve KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#kml_serverv)?